# Alternative to Concat on MySql

Tags: mysql, concatenation

With the following query:

```
"SELECT  
'Week' `key` 
,concat("KW-" ,WEEK(current_date - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) ) as value"
```

I get :

```
Key Value
Week KW-48
```

However when I transform this query to Talend for an automation, it gives me error. Is there any alternative to concat function in Mysql? Thank you.

Comment: CONCAT is the default way to do string concatenation, what is the error?

Comment: The error says: The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String,java.lang.String. This error is from automation in Talend. I normally import mysql to talend.I suppose my version of Talend doesn't recognize concat

Comment: Is it simply that your query contains double-quotes? Perhaps it should be: `"SELECT 'Week' as key, concat('KW-' ,WEEK(current_date - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) ) as value ..."`

Comment: omg this solved my problem :) thank you moob

Comment: I see Moob beat me to it, glad you found the answer.

Comment: @Acerace.py You're welcome. I've posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is also `CONCAT_WS():`

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(SPACE(1), 'Name:','jhon') AS result
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an alternative to concat. Your query (which is already a quoted string) contains another double-quoted string inside it. To fix it, simply wrap the `KW-` bit in single quotes instead of double.

EG:

```
"SELECT 'Week' as key, concat('KW-' ,WEEK(current_date - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) ) as value ..."
```